# Is there a Twitter app that allows filtering of tweets based on source, hashtag, etc?

Tags: twitter

Tweet Deck for PC has a global filter that allows this but I cannot see this option in the Android client.

As above, is there an app that has this feature?

I would very much like to clear my tweetstream of Foursquare noise and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touiteur has been updated today and now has filtering. Please note that this feature may just be the paid version. I'll update this answer with a link and QR code when I've confirmed those details.

Edit: It would seem that filtering isn't a premium feature.

The filtering can be found under the mute settings in Touiteur -> More -> Mute.
You can choose to mute text (inc. hashtags), users and apps (sources).

[Touiteur homepage](http://levelupstudio.com/touiteur)

[image]